# Conditional grouping of records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with grouping records in PostgreSQL. I have a structure containing 3 columns, non unique id, name, group (it's old system and I can't change this structure).

Sample records:

```
  id |   name   | group
-----+----------+------
  1  | product1 | 0
  1  | product1 | test
  2  | product2 | test
  3  | product3 | test123
```

I want the groups unequal 0 to be concatenated (get the id, name of the first record from the group).

The expected result:

```
  id |   name   | group
-----+----------+------
  1  | product1 | 0
  1  | product1 | test
  3  | product3 | test123
```

Currently count records in the following way:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN group = '0' THEN group END) +
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN group <> '0' THEN group END) AS count
FROM
    table
```

Is it correct way? How can I convert it to retrieve records?

Comment: your requirement is not clear , can you try to re frame this sentence - I  want the groups unequal 0 to be concatenated (get the id, name of the first record from the group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, group
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by group order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or group = '0';
```

Note:  `group` is a really bad name for a column.  It is a SQL keyword, so you should escape the name.  I am leaving it as is because your query uses it.